# How do I connect to my Notion API integration using .NET HttpClient? I can connect using Postman, but not my application

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, dotnet-httpclient, notion-api

I can connect to my Notion page using Postman by using the call from [text](https://developers.notion.com/reference/retrieve-a-page).  I am using my internal integration.  I added the Authorization and Notion-Version headers.  My program is a Blazor Server App and am using Visual Studio.  I am not interested in trying Python or JavaScript.  This needs to be Blazor Server.

When I use my code, I get an Authorization error (401).  The else clause executes.  Can you help?

```
private async Task GetDatabaseContent()
{
    string requestUri = $"https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/{pageId}";

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(name: "Authorization", value: $"Bearer {bearerToken}");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(name: "Notion-Version", value: "2022-06-28");

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    try
    {
        response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        responseMessage = $"Exception: {ex}";
    }

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        responseMessage = "Success: " + await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        responseMessage = $"Error: {response.Content}";
        reasonPhrase = $"Error: {response.ReasonPhrase}";
    }
```

I've gone through countless examples from YouTube, I've looked at Pluralsight and Skillshare.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is the title: How do I connect to my Notion API integration using .NET HttpClient?  I've shown the code for what I am doing and asking what I need to change so that I can communicate with my Notion page without getting an Authorization error.

Comment: Are you sure that the `bearerToken` that you have provided is valid and not expired?

Comment: You have `client` and `httpClient`; what is `client`? It looks like you need those to be the same thing.

Comment: The bearerToken value was copy-pasted from the Notion integration so it is valid, and it shouldn’t be expired since I resent the post command in Postman afterwards.  I also verified the value when debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: client is an instance of HttpClient. This was done prior to executing the method.

Comment: Are they the identical instance?  If not, you're setting the headers on one instance then using another - which will not have the auth header - to make the call.

Comment: You found my error.  I had two instances.  I @injected an instance into the page and then created another instance on that page.  Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post it as an answer so that it can be properly evaluated and potentially marked as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comments...

You have 2 instances of `HttpClient`, and are setting the headers, including the authorization one, on one instance - `client` - but sending the request using the other - `httpClient`.

Each instance has its own collection of `DefaultRequestHeaders`, so you need to set the headers on the same instance as used to send the request.

---

Note that it's usually better practice to set (most) headers per-request in a new `HttpRequestMessage`, which you then use with `.SendAsync()`, instead of e.g. `.GetAsync()`.

Unless you have a very simple single-threaded app, `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` should only have headers that are always the same *for every request for the lifetime of your `HttpClient`*, and `HttpClient`'s lifetime would in turn [usually be the lifetime of your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0#instancing).

An Authorization header typically can change - as it expires and is renewed -  during the lifetime of an app, and `DefaultRequestHeaders` [is not thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=net-7.0#remarks):

> Headers set on this property don't need to be set on request messages again. **DefaultRequestHeaders should not be modified while there are outstanding requests**.

It's even more fragile than that implies, and concurrently changing `DefaultRequestHeaders` from more than one thread can be problematic, as underneath it's (typically) just an array that is manipulated without any regard for thread-safety.  Hence in any meaningful multi-threaded app you are creating race conditions whenever you set a `DefaultRequestHeaders` value.